# How convert string to pixels

Tags: wpf, textblock

I have TextBlock with some Text="AAAAAAAA", FontFamily="Arial", FontSize="16".  How I can convert Text to WPF pixels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`FormattedText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.formattedtext.aspx) for measuring:

```
FormattedText formattedText = new FormattedText(
    "AAAAAAAA",
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
    FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
    new Typeface("Arial"), 16, Brushes.Black
);
MessageBox.Show(formattedText.Width.ToString());
```